# Join UICollectionViewCell like HTML rowspan for table?

Tags: ios, html-table, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Is it possible join UICollectionViewCells in iOS like in HTML cell content can join with rowspan or colspan?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the default `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` you can't place a cell in 2 rows, so the "rowspan" is impossible in that case. You can set the width of a cell, so "colspan" is possible". But if you want both, you gotta write a custom layout.

Answer (score 1):

This Project can help you:

https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

This was usefull for me.